# IndexError: list index out of range but the card is starting with zero index

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape one web using python. Here are my code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys  # using for command Line argument
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# generating url for product
def get_url(product):
    product = product.replace(' ','%20')
    template = 'https://www.carousell.com.my/search/{}'
    url = template.format(product_name)
    return url

def get_all_products(card):
    product_image = card.find('img','D_iN D_iK D_uf')
    product_image = product_image['src']
    product_name = card.find('p','D_bU M_ch D_aQ M_aL D_bV M_ci D_bY 
    M_cl D_ca M_cn D_ce M_cq D_ch M_ct D_bR').text.strip()
    product_price = card.find('p','D_bU M_ch D_aQ M_aL D_bV M_ci D_bY 
    M_cl D_ca M_cn D_ce M_cq D_cg M_cs D_bQ').text.strip()
    product_summary = card.find('p','D_bU M_ch D_aQ M_aL D_bV M_ci 
    D_bY M_cl D_ca M_cn D_ce M_cq D_cg M_cs D_bR').text.strip()
    anchor = card.find('a','D_gk M_bj')
    product_link = 'https://www.carousell.com.my'+anchor.get('href')

    product_info = (product_image, product_name, product_price, 
    product_summary, product_link)
    return product_info

def main(product):
    url = get_url(product)
    options = Options()
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('headless')
    options.add_argument('--log-level=3')

    driver = `webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\webDrivers\\chromedriver.exe',options=options)`
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(5)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
    product_card = soup.find_all('div','D_jb D_ph D_pm M_np')

    #fetching single product from Carousell
    singleCard = product_card[0]
    productDetails = get_all_products(singleCard)
    return productDetails

pname = str(sys.argv[1])
scrape_data = main(pname)
print(scrape_data)
```

I got this error when I try to run using cmd:

```
File "C:\wamp\www\project\Carousell_Scrap_PHP.py", line 63, in main
singleCard = product_card[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

i have try to use the same code for shopee and it runs wellbut when i try it with another carousell, it show this error. I also tried to find the answer for this error but I can't get it. I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this. I know indexes  start from `0` but I already write `0` in the code. It still show `indexerror`.

Comment: There must be occasions when `product_card` is an empty list. At this time *all* index values will be out of range.

Comment: but how to fix it? i have no idea when this happen

Comment: But that's not your question. I've answered why you could get an `IndexError`. It must be something to do with the web page you are scraping that yields an empty list.

Comment: What is the exact url you are working  ?

Comment: @cruisepandey url for this coding? this website >> https://www.carousell.com.my   . it tried to display  information for one product but it show indexerror

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error since `product_card` is empty.
This obviously caused by wrong locator `div','D_jb D_ph D_pm M_np` you are using to get these elements.
I couldn't find clear locator for this element here.

```
product_card = soup.find_all('div','.D_ow.D_qW.D_rb')
```

Worked for me

Comment: This possibly should have been a comment !

Comment: Don't worry, I'm trying to give the correct locator too

Comment: Do you think that it will work ? those are all dynamically generated by react js. I don't think that it would work in OP machine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its because there are spaces in the class name `D_jb D_ph D_pm M_np`. Use only the 1st part of the class name. In the [link](https://www.carousell.com.my/search/waist%20bag?addRecent=true&canChangeKeyword=true&includeSuggestions=true&searchId=F7LtXr) for the `div` tag with class `D_ow D_qW D_rb` , tried with only `D_ow` and it returned those 20 items.

```
driver.get("https://www.carousell.com.my/search/waist%20bag?addRecent=true&canChangeKeyword=true&includeSuggestions=true&searchId=F7LtXr")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
product_card = soup.find_all('div','D_ow')
print(len(product_card))
```